# Complex query and getting results by slug instead of ID in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have complex query and relation which I'm not fully understand. I'm kind of new in Laravel. Anyway, I'm looking for a way to load this with slugs instead of ID's.

This is the function in the controller

```
public function index( $category_id)
{
    $Category = new Category;
    $allCategories = $Category->getCategories();
    $category = Category::find($category_id);

    if($category->parent_id == 0) {

         $ids = Category::select('id')->where('parent_id', $category_id)->where('parent_id','!=',0)->get();
         $array = array();

         foreach ($ids as $id) {
            $array[] = (int) $id->id;
         }
         $items = Item::whereIn('category_id',$array)->where('published', 1)->paginate(5);

    } else {
        $items =  Item::where('category_id' ,$category_id)->where('published', 1)->paginate(5);
    }

    return view('list', compact('allCategories','items'));
}
```

Those are relations in the Model

```
public function item()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Item','category_id');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id');
}


public function getCategories()
{
    $categoires = Category::where('parent_id',0)->get();
    $categoires = $this->addRelation($categoires);
    return $categoires;
}
public function selectChild( $id )
{
    $categoires = Category::where('parent_id',$id)->where('published', 1)->paginate(40);
    $categoires = $this->addRelation($categoires);
    return $categoires;
}

public function addRelation( $categoires )
{

  $categoires->map(function( $item, $key)
  {             
        $sub = $this->selectChild($item->id);
        $item->itemCount = $this->getItemCount($item->id , $item->parent_id );
        return $item = array_add($item, 'subCategory', $sub);
    });
    return $categoires;
}
public function getItemCount( $category_id )
{
    return Item::where('category_id', $category_id)->count();
}
```

This is what I have in my routes

```
Route::get('list/{category}', 'ListController@index')->name('list');
```

currently is loading urls like http://example.com/list/1 where 1 is the ID. I'm wonder if with current setup is possible to make it like, http://example.com/slug

I'm aware how slugs are working. I just can't understand how to use them in queries instead of ID's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [explicit Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#explicit-binding) to grab your Category by slug before processing it.

In your `RouteServiceProvider` you need to bind the model:

```
Route::bind('category', function ($value) {
   //Change slug to your column name
   return App\Category::where('slug', $value)->firstOrFail();  
});
```

Then, you can typehint the categories.

For example in your index method:

```
public function index(Category $category)
{
    $Category = new Category;
    $allCategories = $Category->getCategories();
    //This line is obsolete now:
    //$category = Category::find($category_id);

    //...
}
```

Comment: Is this `bind` going into `boot` function?

Comment: @Peter Yeah, as shown in the docs you need to write it after `parent::boot();`

Comment: Bellow this line `//$category = Category::find($category_id);` there is IF statement which is using this variable `$category` and now return undefined.

Comment: Well, if the category is right (you can check that with a fast `dd`), then you should look into your logic in general.

Comment: `$item` is returning empty collection.

Comment: Looks like it's a bug in your logic

Comment: Okay, managed to make it to work. But here is one interesting question(at least for me) what if I want to make another pretty url from another controller and model? Can I place second bind in `RouteServiceProvider`?

Comment: You can always add bindings to the Service Provider, as long the names stay unique.

Comment: Thanks. Wow, I tough it will be really pain to convert this urls.

Comment: By `as long the names stay unique` do you mean the DB column names?

Comment: No, I mean the model binding name in `Route::bind('thisonehere',..)`. The column you choose for retrieving the models must be unique too of course.

Comment: Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your index function parameter from `$category_id` to `$category_slug`

Remove this line  `$Category = new Category;`

And change this `$category = Category::find($category_id);`

To this: `$category = Category::where('slug', $category_slug)->first();`

*Assuming that you have a unique `slug` in category table

Comment: I get `Undefined variable: category_id` on line `$items =  Item::where('category_id' ,$category_id)->where('published', 1)->paginate(5);` when I change to slug parameter

Comment: change all variables`$category_id` in your index function to `$category->id`

Comment: in your database what is the id of the category?? category_id? or id?

Comment: in Items table is `category_id` in Category table is `id`

Comment: you have a slug field in Category?

Comment: check if you have items that meet this condition  `$items =  Item::where('category_id' ,$category_id)->where('published', 1)->paginate(5);` .. you can dd($items); before your return statement to see what items has in it.

Comment: I have one item assigned in that category. The field in database is `alias` which I use for `slug` and I expecting 1 item on page but non are shown

Comment: published value is  1?

Comment: Yes. Published is 1

Comment: you should have Category::where('alias', $category_slug) then?

Comment: Yes, and the page is loaded blank but 1 item is expected

Comment: try this before your return statement : `dd($items);` and then this `dd($category);` and tell me if you get any results

Comment: `dd($category);` return correct category. `dd($items);` return empty collection `#items: Collection {#375 ▼ #items: [] }`. With ID is working and item is returned.

Comment: the parent_id is 0 of the current category?

Comment: The @manniL answer is works and returns the items in category.

Comment: Thanks for the help!